# Chrome Developer Tools debugger doesn't seem to halt in certain parts of javascript file

Tags: javascript

I want to halt the debugger inside the modifyDOM function however it seems to just go right over it. It does stop at other points though, I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the way javascript works which I don't yet to understand (very new to the language).

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("Popup DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    function modifyDOM() {
        debugger;
        //You can play with your DOM here or check URL against your regex
        console.log('Tab script:');
        console.log(document.body);
        return document.body.innerHTML;
    }

    //We have permission to access the activeTab, so we can call chrome.tabs.executeScript:
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: '(' + modifyDOM + ')();' //argument here is a string but function.toString() returns function's code
    }, (results) => {
        //Here we have just the innerHTML and not DOM structure
        console.log('Popup script:')
        console.log(results[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll need to include the parentheses in your function call.  `'(' + modifyDOM() + ')();'` You could also define the function as a variable and leave the call as-is. `var modifyDOM = function () {...}`

Comment: The first method kind of worked. The debugger stopped however modifyDOM was not logging the web page anymore but instead it was logging the small page on the popup itself. 

If I remove the parentheses and go back to the original code, it prints out the DOM for the web page.

(My end goal is to make a plugin that edits some values in a table which appears after a few clicks.)